# Outer product of Gaussian vectors conditioned on their scaled sum being large

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, gaussian

Consider $e\in \mathbb{R}^d$, for which $e_1, \ldots, e_d$ are independently drawn from a Gaussian,  $e_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \epsilon)$. Let $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^d, ||\mu||_2 \leq D$. Then, what is known about $\lambda_\min(Y)$, the minimum eigenvalue of $Y$, where

$$ Y = \mathbb{E_{e}}\left[e e^T | \langle e , \mu \rangle \geq c\right],$$

presumably in terms of $\epsilon, d, D,$ and $c$?

Alternatively, understanding the distribution over $e e^T$ with the same conditioning would be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Just to clarify, $\langle e , \mu \rangle=e^T\mu$ correct?

Comment: I mean standard inner (dot) product of those two vectors...

Comment: I am confused...how is the standard inner product different from $x^T y$ if all you considered is $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: It is the same.